# Консольное приложение Yii2 со временем увеличивается время работы скрипта

Tags: yii2, консоль, производительность

Есть консольное приложение - заполняет таблицу на основании данных из другой таблицы. Берется выборка 1000 записей, в цикле формирую строку для вставки batchInsert, вставляю. Следующий кусок и так далее.
Вопрос: каждая следующая итерация по времени выполняется дольше. Время все время растет. 
Все переменные через unset в цикле очищаются. Логирование отключил. Думаю что то "жрет" память. Размер "куска" изменял, не принципиально. Все равно чем дольше работает скрипт, тем увеличивается время итерации. Данные для обработки в принципе одинаковые (по объему). В какую сторону еще посмотреть?

Comment: Делайте insert не одной записи, а многих.
Я когда-то исследовал эту тему.
Сделайте 2 инсерта по 500 записей, и все будет молниеносно, если нет доп. логики из-за которой нужно делать только одиночные вставки

Comment: batchInsert это и есть пакетная вставка. Вставляется весь "кусок", в цикле формируется массив для вставки. В конце вставляется.

Comment: Это косяк Yii2. Не помню точно подробностей, но как-то заливали много строк, тоже резали пачками по 300к, и с каждой итерацией время увеличивалось и память росла. В итоге скрипт рано или поздно отваливался по памяти. Если изучить работу batchInsert, то там будет видно, почему так происходит. Это было на 2.0.15 версии.

Comment: Спасибо @fedornabilkin  Именно batchInsert
решение: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420959/yii2-batchinsert-eats-all-server-memory

Comment: Добавь ответ, я его в избранное добавлю. Пусть на русском тоже будет свой вариант, как победить batchInsert.

Comment: Вместо 20 часов формирования таблицы получилось 5

Answer (score 3):

Класс в common/components

```
<?php
namespace common\components;
use yii\log\Logger;
class EmptyLogger extends Logger
{
    public function log($message, $level, $category = 'application')
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

В консольном контроллере, подключаем класс, инициализируем:

```
<?php
namespace console\controllers;
use common\components\EmptyLogger;
use Yii;
use yii\console\Controller;
class TempController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        Yii::setLogger(new EmptyLogger());
        ...

        Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
            ->batchInsert(static::tableName(), $columns, $rows)
            ->execute();
        ...
    }
}
```

Мы отключили логгер. Проблема в том что данные запроса сохраняются для логгера и передаются в диспетчер согласно настройкам, по достижению размера например. Так как скрипт большой (таблица большая) и к логам не обращаемся, то данные просто висят в памяти. Причем отключить логирование не помогает. Может это не совсем правильно, но если мне нужно формировать таблицу не чистым sql, то это вариант.