# Как загружать большой прайс в mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Суть задачи: загрузить прайс (около 1 милиона позиций) через веб интерфейс. Сейчас этот интерфейс есть и он работает, но заметил такое: первых 100 тыс грузит быстро, дальше начинает грузить медленно (иногда для полной загрузки надо более 20 мин, а иногда вообще база "падает").

Есть ли решение, как можно быстро грузить такие большие прайсы? Или как вообще правильно обрабатывать такие большие прайсы?

Прайсы в формате xlsx, xls, csv, для написания веб интерфейса использовал Yii2.

Так же сразу замечу, что индексы есть, все возможные настройки для mysql сделал

Comment: Что из себя представляет "загрузка прайса" ? Его что то парсит предварительно, как выглядит формирование запроса и сам запрос к таблице. Какова структура таблицы и каковы индексы (вы же понимаете, что наличие индексов ускоряет поиск, но замедляет вставку). Во время загрузки, что на сколько потребляет процессор, сколько скрипт и сколько БД. Многое имеет значение, а информации в вопросе категорически не достаточно

Comment: получение информации с массива происходит быстро, менее 1 секунды. по поводу таблицы и индексов - http://joxi.ru/Grqp6qotkQ7nnA

Comment: Это ничего не говорит, потому что мы даже не знаем, что именно тормозит, что происходит с системой во время загрузки. Не известно даже БД виновата или может скрипт. А может скрипт держит весь массив данных в памяти, ее начинает в системе не хватать и все ложиться в свап, включая MySQL, приводя к катастрофической деградации скорости всей системы

Comment: Если в процессе начинает замедляться, значит кто-то набирает памяти. запись в БД с помощью batchInsert Yii2? В старых версиях этот метод хорошо набирал память и падал. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1010672/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-yii2-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0

Comment: @fedornabilkin, нет, просто createCommand(). По поводу нагрузок посмотрю, спасибо